# NSFetchedResultsController:didChangeObject different type in iOS8 and iOS9

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am finding a weird issue with `NSFetchedResultsController:didChangeObject` . The changetype is sent wrongly in `iOS8` and `iOS9` for the same use-case. My app is built using XCode7.2

In `iOS8` - If I do a tableview refresh I get the change type as update `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`, if there is any update and at the same time if I do it in iOS9 for the same usecase I get change type as `NSFetchedResultsChangeMove`, though nothing is moved.

Outcome:
In `iOS9` the table view applies move animation though nothing is moved, for every refresh, its looks annoying for the users.

Have any of you faced this issue?

Comment: So what is the refresh / trigger / actual change to the data store? How is the FRC fetch constructed?

Comment: When I pull the tableview to refresh, I am calling a webservice to get the data, the data is then inserted to the db. Each data has an internal order based on which it is sorted. In this case there is no change in the internal order so tables should not move.